# How to explain computer security to low-grade students?

Tags: professional-education

This is my first question here on Security, so please forgive me if I'm in the wrong place for asking this.

I am a computer science teacher currently teaching classes of teenage students age between 14 and 16. I want to give my class some lectures about "Computer Security"; I write it with quotes because they are not computer scientist at all, I just taught them a bit of programming, so what I need might not be exactly classified as "Computer Security".

What I am actually looking for is a good starting point (resources, books, blog posts, ecc.) to give them a glance about security from an end-user point of view like, for example, using smart passwords, good practices when surfing the Web, all those things that we, as computer guys, (should) use.

Can anybody help me on this quest?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start from something similar to this guide: http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/support/winsupuser/homeuser. It has further reading references and I think that for kids that age, besides basic security information, you should teach them about privacy and what should and what should not be posted online and how hard it is to take something offline (a shared photo for example) once it was on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chap who runs ISECOM (Pete Herzog) has an initiative called "Hacker High School" (he mentions them in nearly every email he sends out!)

http://www.hackerhighschool.org/lessons.html

There's an interview here about it:
http://www.securitybistro.com/blog/?p=3952

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the USA, consider looking into the CyberPatriot competition.  You may already have a local team you could tap for resources - your nearby Civil Air Patrol wing might have more info.

http://www.uscyberpatriot.org/Pages/default.aspx